# Elasticsearch and Drupal, sort: No mapping found for [field_XX] in order to sort on

Tags: php, elasticsearch, drupal

In my query I want to sort results. My request doesn't generate error but  "sort" doesn't work.

```
...[sort] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [field_title] => Array
        (
            [order] => asc
        )
    )
)...
```

I work with Drupal, my index is already create. I think that I miss a mapping. But I don't know how to create a "mapping" so that "sort" works. In the elasticsearch.yml file? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ElasticSearch ignores unmapped field when sorting. 
Just try to add a mapping for the *title_field*

> By default, the search request will fail if there is no mapping
>   associated with a field.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_ignoring_unmapped_fields

Comment: I add "unmapped_type"=> "string", and i change the type of my title_field (type==string, not fulltext)